Steps to redeploy a Teams Apps after applying some changes and deploy it to local GIT repo
We already have a Teams Apps installed inside our Microsoft Teams Admin Center, the apps is inside GitHub @ https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-emergency-operations-center. Now we want to do some changes that will not be deployed to the upstream. So i did those steps:-

Clone the GitHub code locally
Do the modifications using Visual Studio code.
then push the changes to our BitBucket repository which is public
Now I will redeploy the manifest.json + the resources images to the Microsoft Teams Admin center.
I will modify the "Git Repo URL" field inside the existing custom deployment template ,


to reference our custom Repo inside Bitbucket instead of the upstream GitHub?
My first question, are my above steps valid? and all the required steps? and can i modify the "GIT Repo URL" for existing template?
Second question, now inside our public Bitbucket repo we will have the ClientID and appdomain inside the manifest.json .. so can we hide them? or they will need to be there for the "Git Repo Url" to reference them? or those values are only needed inside the manifest .json uploaded inside our Microsoft Teams admin center? and doe snot require to be inside the public bitbucket repository?
Thanks
